# How to make git feature branches work with jenkins-workflow?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I'm trying to setup jenkins-workflow to do our integration tests. Our integration tests work like this:

Someone makes a change to `LibraryA` in a feature branch in git. We would like jenkins to run the unit tests against the code in the feature branch, then we would like to install the code from this feature branch into `client1` and `client2` (which are users of `LibraryA`) and run their tests.

I was able to setup a workflow to do everything except get the right commit to the feature branch of `LibraryA`. Instead, my setup just pulls a commit from some (seemingly random) branch of `LibraryA`.

We have lots of feature branches, so hardcoding a particular branch in the workflow setup doesn't see appropriate. It seems like there should be some way to get the hash of the commit that triggers the workflow job (even when using SCM polling).

My setup looks like this:

```
currentBuild.setDisplayName("#" + env.BUILD_NUMBER)

node {
  git credentialsId: '033df7f1-7752-46bd-903d-8a70e613eed0', url: 'git@github.com:mycompany/myrepo.git'
  sh '''
echo `git rev-parse HEAD` > libraryA_version.txt
sudo docker run --rm=true -e LANG=en_US.UTF-8 -a stdout -i -t mycompany/libraryA run_tests
'''
  archive 'libraryA_version.txt'
}

def integration_jobs = [:]

integration_jobs[0]={
  node{
    ws {
      unarchive mapping: ['libraryA_version.txt':'.']
      sh 'sudo docker run -t --rm mycompany/client1:v1 bash run_tests.sh "`cat libraryA_version.txt`"'
    }
  }
}

integration_jobs[1] = {
  node{
    ws {
      unarchive mapping: ['libraryA_version.txt' : '.']
      sh 'sudo docker run -t --rm mycompany/client2 run_tests.sh "`cat libraryA_version.txt`" '
    }
  }
}

parallel integration_jobs
```

So, my current question is how can I setup the git repo/polling to get the right commit to run in the first test, which will be used in `libraryA_version.txt` in subsequent tests?

Alternatively, should I go about this process in a completely different way?

Answer (score 4):

As @maybeg hinted, what you are most likely looking for is a multibranch project, available by installing *Pipeline: Multibranch*. That lets you define the script in a `Jenkinsfile` which simply calls `checkout scm` one or more times in your build, avoiding the need for `libraryA_version.txt`.

In the meantime, I am left wondering about your project setup. Your `git` step is using the default of `branch: 'master'`, meaning it should only be polling on the `master` branch to begin with, and only checking out this branch. The Git plugin is rather complicated, so perhaps this is broken somehow. Pending proper multibranch support, you could always use the `checkout` step with a `GitSCM` configured to use a wildcard branch spec, in which case an arbitrary branch head not previously built will be selected for checkout, and your `git-rev-parse` trick (I guess you independently rediscovered the workaround for [JENKINS-26100](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26100)) ought to work as is.

Comment: Ok, so to reflect back, in a workflow job, configure scm polling to trigger the job when a commit is made, then use the `checkout` step with a wildcard branch (**). It will select a branch with a head that has not been built, ideally the branch of the commit that triggered the job?

Comment: Right, there is no guarantee that the selected head commit will be the trigger cause, but it is likely. Not sure offhand what will happen if multiple eligible heads are discovered in one polling session—it might trigger multiple builds, though whenever using SCM polling (incl. the `/git/notifyCommit` webhook) it is wise to add `@daily`/`@hourly` to the schedule to catch any stray commits. Again, using an upcoming multibranch workflow this all becomes easier: each branch gets its own subproject, and the notation `checkout scm` may be used ≥1 times to get matching checkouts.

Comment: I was able to use the `branch: "production"` nomenclature with the new Pipeline job plugin under Jenkins ver. 1.634.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are looking for is Build-Per-Branch and in my view it should be implemented accordingly through fit-for-purpose plugins.

- Branching is done in git.
- Jenkins must copy the build or build pipeline job to fit the branch and being able to build and test the branch.
- After reintegration git must inform Jenkins and Jenkins must shut down the jobs.

I found this plugin:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multi-Branch+Project+Plugin

And this plugin/tutorial:

http://entagen.github.io/jenkins-build-per-branch/

The implementation is strongly dependent on your scenario so i can't be more specific. I just say the challenges are:

- Building Jenkins jobs that can run concurrently and independently.
- Working with templates for Jenkins jobs.
- Handling events between Jenkins and git.

In your case:

- Build the whole process as a delivery pipeline from front to end.
- If someone branches a step and implements a feature then copy the whole pipeline and run the whole pipeline.
- Get this working then improve.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. This is how we started out. We have a multi-job tool chain that works, but it has undesirable qualities. It doesn't scale with our repos in the sense that we have too many jobs to manage. The failure notifications and culprits don't work well. The setup across jobs is unwieldily. This is why the jenkins-workflow plugin is nice -- the setup for an entire integration chain is in one, fairly compact job.

Comment: Then lets answer your original question, here is a list of jenkins job env variables: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project. In your case GIT_COMMIT and GIT_BRANCH should be the infos your looking for in building your workflow.

Comment: I print out my env vars at the top of the job and those aren't available. Apparently, jenkins-workflow job doesn't set those GIT variables.

"The following variables are currently unavailable inside a workflow script:

EXECUTOR_NUMBER
NODE_NAME
NODE_LABELS
WORKSPACE
SCM-specific variables such as SVN_REVISION"

Comment: Looks like we got stuck with jenkins-workflow. Another possible solution would be to go away from git/branches/commits and take a look at the artifact repository.  Not each time a commit occured it should be checked out and build but each time an artifact with label "xy" has been deployed by the ci job it should be put inside the container and tested. Look here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/FSTrigger+Plugin